# having trouble adding html to with jQuery

Tags: jquery, thickbox

I have a link on the page which when clicked opens up a thick-box window with Ajax modal login content. What is odd is that if I remove the `alert('');` the next jquery line of code does not work. `$('#logintest').before('<input type="hidden" value="' +st+ '" name="ReturnTo">');`

If the `alert('');` is there the hidden input is added to the thickbox modal window before the input with the id of "logintest" as it should.

I haven't been able to figure out why, anyone?

Here is the code on the main page

```
<a class="login_links" id="myaccount" href="/myaccount.asp">My Account</a>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function(){
$(".login_links").click(function(){   
var t = this.title || null;
var s = $(this).attr("href");
var g = this.rel || false;
var l = '/v/AjaxLogin.asp?height=100&width=300&modal=true'
tb_show(t,l,g);
var st = s.substr(s.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
alert('');
$('#logintest').before('<input type="hidden" value="' +st+ '" name="ReturnTo">');
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

And here is the code on the ajax page

```
<div style="text-align:center ">
<form action="/login.asp" method="post" name="loginform">
<table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" style="margin:0 auto;">
<tr>
    <td>Username:</td>
        <td><input type="text" maxlength="75" size="30" value="" name="email"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td>Password:</td>
        <td align="left"><input id="logintest" type="password" maxlength="20" size="20" name="password"></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Login">&nbsp;<input type="submit" id="cancel" value="Cancel" onclick="tb_remove();return false;"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: @nick: its function from thickbox, that essentially shows the hidden "lightbox" div. If i recall correctly tb_show actually does some async dom manipulation and building when its invoked. Id wager tht the reason it works with the alert is that its adding a delay which is just long enough for tb_show to finish its work

Comment: The function is a little long to post here, let me see if I can link to it.

Comment: The delay was my thought exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax loading is asynchronous. The reason its not working without the alert is because the html from the ajax request hasnt been appended to the dom yet. You need to move that code to the success callback. Im not sure if TB provides for that or not.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my original thoughts.